# Django: How to subtract two model fields in Django templates(html file)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have one model called `Installment` and it has one field called `balance`. My models.py is given below:

models.py

```
class Installment(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    installment_month = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    installment_amount = models.IntegerField()
    installment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    # Calcuting balance
    def calculate_balance(self):
        #self.aggregate(sum=Sum('installment_amount'))
        balance = (self.client.total_price - self.client.down_payment)
        return balance

    # Saving balance
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.balance = self.calculate_balance()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am calculating this balance field from two fields of other model called `Client`.

Now, my views for showing the list of installment of each particular client is below:

views.py

```
class InstallmentListView(ListView):
    model = Installment
    template_name = 'client_management_system/installment_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'installments'

    # This function is to show the installments of the client, the details of which we are seeing currently, and
    # pk=self.kwargs['pk'] is to get the client id/pk from URL
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Installment.objects.filter(client=user).annotate(
            total=Window(
                expression=(self.balance - Sum('installment_amount')),
                order_by=F('installment_date').asc(),
                frame=RowRange(end=0)
            )
        )
```

In the views above, we are calculating a new field called `total`using window function, and I have written `self.balance` here in the expression to subtract the `Sum` of `installment_amount` from `balance` and save the results in `total`. But I am getting the following error:

Error:

```
AttributeError at /1/Installment-History/
'InstallmentListView' object has no attribute 'balance'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/Installment-History/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'InstallmentListView' object has no attribute 'balance'
Exception Location: /Users/razajaved/Documents/installment_plan/client_management_system/views.py, line 78, in get_queryset
Python Executable:  /anaconda3/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/razajaved/Documents/installment_plan',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa']
Server time:    Tue, 20 Apr 2021 03:40:00 +0000
```

My html file is below:

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "client_management_system/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"><h5>Installment History</h5></legend>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div>
      <table id="installmentTable" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:150px">Date</th>
          <th style="width:250px">Installment Month</th>
          <th style="width:170px">Amount</th>
          <th style="width:100px">Balance</th>
        </tr>
        {% for installment in installments %}
        <fieldset>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_date|date:"F d, Y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_month }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.total }}</td>
          </tr>
        </fieldset>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

**Does anyone has an idea how to perform this subtraction in this case? And where the subtraction should be performed? In views.py or in html file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` at that point of the code refers to the instance of the class `InstallmentListView`, if you want to refer to the column `balance` of the current row in the query use [`F()` expressions [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).
Furthermore such expressions don't make sense in window functions rather you should use another annotation to do this:

```
Installment.objects.filter(client=user).annotate(
    total=Window(
        expression=Sum('installment_amount'),
        order_by=F('installment_date').asc(),
        frame=RowRange(end=0)
    )
).annotate(some_suitable_name_here=F('balance') - F('total'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is giving the following error `Expression 'CombinedExpression' isn't compatible with OVER clauses `

Comment: @RazaJaved Ah yes, that doesn't make much sense there as it is not a window compatible expression. Use another annotation to do that. Check my edit.